# topbarUpdate and dynamicInit failed (20: Not a directory)

Tags: nginx, horde

I just installed this webmail in a subdomain and I enter well, but when I give the inbox everything appears blank and a red alert telling me that there is no connection to the server, however, decteta that there are 3 emails without read:

[Inbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ka4Ul.png) 
[Red alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93v3i.png)

Nginx log error:

```
2017/06/06 10:14:41 [error] 3057#3057: *3050 open() "/srv/www/correo/services/ajax.php/horde/topbarUpdate" failed (20: Not a directory), client: 195.16.143.6, server: correo.domain.com, request: "POST /services/ajax.php/horde/topbarUpdate HTTP/1.1", host: "correo.domain.com", referrer: "https://correo.domain.com/imp/dynamic.php?page=mailbox"
```

configuración de:

Nginx Settings:

`        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /rampage.php?$args;
        }

```
    #location / {
    #}

    location ~ \.php {
            #fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "cgi.fix_pathinfo=1";
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/correo.sock;
            #fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
            #fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            #root /srv/www/correo/;
            #fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;

            # pvanthony added this because of timeout problem when
            # importing addressbook.
            #fastcgi_connect_timeout 300s;
            #fastcgi_send_timeout 300s;
            #fastcgi_read_timeout 300s;

            #fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
            #fastcgi_buffers 256 4k;
            #fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
            #fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
            #fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt)$ {
            root /srv/www/correo/;
    }
```

`

In /srv/www/correo/imp/config/backends.php I have changed port 443 for 993 which is the port I have configured in postfix for IMAP

Comment: You probably want to get rid of the `$` at the end of the location spec (so just `location ~ \.php {`) otherwise it isn't going to match all the PHP requests.

Comment: The problem persists:

`2017/06/06 12:10:29 [error] 3058#3058: *3233 open() "/srv/www/correo/services/ajax.php/imp/dynamicInit" failed (20: Not a directory), client: 195.16.143.6, server: correo.domain.com, request: "POST /services/ajax.php/imp/dynamicInit HTTP/1.1", host: "correo.domain.com", referrer: "https://correo.domain.com/imp/dynamic.php?page=mailbox"`

Answer (score 0):

I at the end reboot the server and fixed the problem